# Convert Binary Tree to doubly linked list. How can I avoid using global variable here?

Tags: python

The convert function converts the binary tree to linked list. I couldn't pass test cases in geeksforgeek because of using global variable. How can I avoid using a global variable?

```
 prev = None
 head = None

def convert(root):
    global prev
    global head
    if root is None:
        return 

    convert(root.left)
    if head== None:
        head = root
        prev = root
    else:
        root.left = prev
        prev.right = root
    prev = root
    convert(root.right)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your function *return* the `head` after conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass them as arguments with default=None:

```
def convert(root, prev = None, head = None):
    if root is None:
        return 

    convert(root.left, prev=prev, head=head)
    if head== None:
        head = root
        prev = root
    else:
        root.left = prev
        prev.right = root
    prev = root
    convert(root.right, prev=prev, head=head)
```

Comment: I mean, that's a separate issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would need to *return* the head of the linked list.

Any way, you can wrap your function to create a closure for those two variables:

```
def convert(root):
    head = None
    prev = None

    def recur(cur):
        nonlocal prev, head

        if cur is None:
            return 
    
        recur(cur.left)
        if head is None:
            head = cur
        else:
            cur.left = prev
            prev.right = cur
        prev = cur
        recur(cur.right)

    recur(root)
    return head
```